# Problems with wrapping C++ class to python

Tags: python, c++, c, sockets, ctypes

For my project (ia for a game) I need a C network interface. I want to code my project in Python so I created a C++ wrapper from C TCP-Socket functions, to use it with `c-types` in my Python code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Socket.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void        Socket::s_connect(char *host, int port){
    const char *str;
    pe = getprotobyname("tcp");
    if (!pe){
        perror("Error get protocol");
        exit(1);
    }
    f = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, pe->p_proto);
    if (f == -1){
        perror("Error create socker");
        exit(1);
    }
    s_in.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    s_in.sin_port        = htons(port);
    s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);
    if (connect(f, (const struct sockaddr *&)s_in, sizeof(s_in)) == -1){
        perror("Error on connect");
        close(f);
    }
}


void        Socket::s_send(char *msg){
    if (write(f, msg, strlen(msg)) == -1){
        printf("error write\n");
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
}

char        *Socket::s_recv(){
    char    *buff;
    int     ret;

    buff = (char *)malloc(4096);
    ret = read(f, buff, 4096);
    if (ret < 0){
        if (close(f))
            exit(1);
    }
    return buff;
}
extern "C" {
    Socket  *Socket_new()
    {
        return (new Socket); 
    }

    void    Socket_connect(Socket *sock, char *host, int port)
    {
        sock->s_connect(host, port);
    }

    void    Socket_send(Socket *sock, char *msg)
    {
        sock->s_send(msg);
    }
}
```

Socket.h :

```
#ifndef SOCKET_HPP_
# define SOCKET_HPP_


#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>

class Socket {
    int                 f, port;
    struct protoent     *pe;
    struct sockaddr_in  s_in;
    char                *ip;
public:
    void s_connect(char *host, int port);
    void s_send(char * msg);
    char *s_recv();
};

#endif
```

And there is my Python class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libsocket.so')

class Socket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Socket_new()


    def s_connect(self, host, port):
        print(host, port)
        lib.Socket_connect(self.obj, host, int(port))


    def s_send(self, msg):
        lib.Socket_send(self.obj, msg)

    def s_recv(self):
        lib.Socket_recv(self.obj)

    def main(arg):
        sock = Socket()
        sock.s_connect(arg[1], arg[2])
        sock.s_send("coucou")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)
```

And My extern `C func` can't read my string sent from Python I can send a port number but my C++ function can't read the host's string value.
If I change `char *` to `std::string` I get the same problem.
Did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's a heck of a lot easier to use the python `socket` module.

Comment: Yes i know, but my projet requires a C network interface, it's my one of my project's instruction.

Comment: Hmm, do you use Python2 or Python3? It matters for the size of characters...

Comment: When you say "can't read the host's string value", what exactly happens?

Comment: Hang-on, where do you map python to your C++ class?  `libsocket.so` is part of the standard C networking library.   Are you calling your C++ DLL the same name as the C library one?

Comment: @SergeBallesta i use Python 3

Comment: @cdarke yes i called it with the same name, so there is a conflict

Comment: @cdarke even if i change the shared library's name i can't send string to my c++ functions

Comment: What do you mean by "can't send", what error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you use a Python 3 version, the documentation for the `ctypes` module states that Python unicode strings (`str`) correspond to wide character arrays in C (`wchar_t *`), and that Python byte strings (`bytes`) correspond to narrow character arrays (`char *`).

So depending if you want to actually process unicode characters, you should:

- either use `bytes` Python side (trivial):

  ```
  sock.s_connect(arg[1].encode('latin1'), arg[2])
  ```
- or use `wchar_t` C side (probably harder...)